# Enum problems when loading 64bit c DLLs in 64bit Delphi

Tags: c++, c, delphi, dll, enums

I'm making 64bit Delphi export programme which uses 64bit c DLLs. The problem I get is that c DLL doesn't recognise Delphi enums and returns error for the wrong data type. I've tried using {$packenums} or {$Z} directives to Delphi compiler but still same error was returned. I'm using xe8 Delphi. The enum looks like:

```
type  
DDCDataType=(
    DDC_notype = 0,
    DDC_UInt8 = 5,  // unsigned char
    DDC_Int16 = 2,  // short
    DDC_Int32 = 3,  // int
    DDC_Float = 9,  // float -> single
    DDC_Double = 10,    // double
    DDC_String  = 23    // string
);
```

in the c header looks like

```
typedef enum {
    DDC_UInt8 = 5,  // unsigned char
    DDC_Int16 = 2,  // short
    DDC_Int32 = 3,  // int
    DDC_Float = 9,  // float
    DDC_Double = 10,    // double
    DDC_String = 23,    // string
    DDC_Timestamp = 30, // timestamp (Year/Month/Day/Hour/Minute/Second/Millisecond components)
} DDCDataType;
```

I hope this makes sense :) 
Thanks!

Comment: Not making very much sense here. Why have you commented out the values? Surely they are important. And can't we see the C code too? How else are we going to know what the target is. Leaving aside your problem, here is an opportunity to learn with my simple SO interop maxim: *an interop question always needs to present both sides of the interop boundary*. You only presented one side.

Comment: I have tried both with comment and no and was working the same so that why i left them.

Comment: How could it possibly work if you supplied the wrong values. Trial and error. Does that ever work for you?

Comment: Works for 32bit version of programme

Comment: Not likely. Specifying the wrong values won't work ever.

Comment: Regarding, `{$packenums}`, there is no such directive in Delphi. Are you using Delphi? If you are, then what is `{$packenums}`?

Comment: Again with the trial and error. Allow me to recommend, based on my 35 years of experience, that trial and error will not be productive. What you need is to do some debugging. Find some real information and take decisions based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C code, `DDCDataType` is simply an `int`. Which means it has size 4. In your Delphi code, with default compiler settings, the enumerated type has size 1. You should use `{$Z4}` to match the C code.

You probably don't want to use `{$Z4}` throughout your project, so you should just place it in your Delphi interop unit. The unit that defines the types and functions that are imported. If you have mixed up that interop code with your other application logic, take the chance now to maintain a clear separation.

You haven't translated the type faithfully though. You added a value, and missed a value. It should be:

```
{$Z4}
type  
  DDCDataType=(
    DDC_UInt8 = 5,      // unsigned char
    DDC_Int16 = 2,      // short
    DDC_Int32 = 3,      // int
    DDC_Float = 9,      // float
    DDC_Double = 10,    // double
    DDC_String = 23,    // string
    DDC_Timestamp = 30, // timestamp (Year/Month/Day/Hour/Minute/Second/Millisecond components)
  );
```

With that declaration you can be confident that this type matches your C code exactly. There are quite possibly other problems in your program. If the rest of your program fails, please don't be surprised. I've just answered the question that you have asked here.

To be completely clear, if you use the declaration above, and your program still fails, then you know to look elsewhere for the cause.

Comment: I'm just answering the question you asked. Obviously I cannot debug the other code that isn't here. How would I be able to do that. Looks like my final paragraph was prescient. Rather than hoping that we can debug your program from afar why not debug it yourself? It might be easier for you than for us.

Comment: @Primus: David Heffernan's translation is correct. As he said, if you still have problems, it is not because of the declaration of the enum. But it would not surprise me if you had other problems resulting from a wrong conversion of the C code. Take a look at my article ["Pitfalls of converting"](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html) to learn more about converting such header files. Especially take a look at record alignment, parameters and calling conventions, which are, when done wrongly, often the cause of failure.